# Schedule job using non Gregorian calendar cron expression

Tags: java, cron, schedule, quartz, hijri

Is there a way to schedule cron jobs using the Islamic Calendar? Ideally:

```
CronExpression cronExpression = new CronExpression("0 0 0 1 * ? *", CalendarEnum.ISLAMIC);
```

I'm struggling to find the smallest clue on Java Quartz documentation (1 mention on QA section) and I've inspected the source code and found out that the default calendar (found it in *CronExpression.java*) is the Gregorian. Is there a way to achieve this by using the inclusion/exclusion org.quartz.Calendar? I think not, right?

Does anyone have knowledge of how to extend/implement different variations of cron expression to cover e.g. an Islamic calendar? Or alternative open source libraries (hosted on mvn central repo)? Or any approach at all, to achieve an abstracted way of expressing recurrence (e.g. repeat every 1st day of each Islamic month)?

Temporarily, I'm thinking of manually binding multiple org.quartz.Trigger dates to the job (converted from Islamic to Gregorian). But, this is not optimal since a single cron expression may result in a dozen or hundred of dates.

Sorry, for the not so technical question, but the topic seems to be uncovered and information sparse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Islamic Calendar and the Gregorian Calendar are not aligned and the Islamic Months have a different length then the Gregorian Months, it is rather tricky. I would suggest performing a cron implementation of the following style (Linux Cron Style):

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *   command to be executed
  x  y  *  *  *   IslamicMonthTestCmd && command
```

The idea is to do daily a test at `x` hours and `y` minutes to check if you are on the first of the Islamic Month. This is done by `IslamicMonthTestCmd` which you still have to write yourself. If this test passes then you execute `command`.

Writing this `IslamicMonthTestCmd` is not straightforward as the Islamic Calendar, in contrary to the Gregorian, is heavily influenced by Men. The months depend on the visibility of the new moon by religious authorities and can, therefore, vary by a day or two, clearly influenced by the people, weather and various other disturbances. The current Islamic year is 1440 AH. In the Gregorian calendar, 1440 AH runs from **approximately** 11 September 2018 to 30 August 2019. **<sup>[source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar)]</sup>**

Comment: As you said, Cron can be used if a calendar is aligned with the Gregorian one. The parts that are aligned with the Islamic calendar; thus can be used in a cron expression, is the time and the day of the week. Using Cron for the day of the month, the month, and the year is not possible.

Comment: @LovaBill To expand a bit.  It is indeed true that you can work with day-of-week, minutes, hours in cron. But if you have a mapping function, you could translate the calendars completely. I read a bit more on the Islamic calendar, and even though the original calendar is based on observations, you could use computations based on pure mathematical algorithms. The `ical` program uses that. So using `ical` you could write a conversion tool `IslamicMonthTestCmd` which essentially checks if you can run your cron or not.